# Opposing EMF's with an odd change...?

Tags: voltage, resistance, electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnetic

A conductor in **case 1** has two separate uniform magnetic fields   \$B_1\$ & \$B_2\$:
[image]

The magnetic fields(**the blue rectangles are the field regions parallel to the conductor, while X's are the field lines going into the page**) both changing at the same rate over the same duration of time, inducing an EMF(\$\epsilon\$) on each part with respect to their magnetic fields.However, \$B_1\$'s change is in a way that it's induced \$\epsilon\$ opposes the other:

[image]

Now it's quite simple to solve, since this is not a closed loop(only focusing on EMF) the net EMF would be (A) $$ V_n = V_2 - V_1 = 0$$

However, what if I changed things in **case 2**, by changing the region of the magnetic field of \$B_1\$ , yet made the rate of change between the two fields the same, so that their induced EMF's are both the same:
[image]

What is the end result here? I don't know how this affects the induced EMF's cancelling each other; they are still the same and opposing one another:

[image]

With that change, is this expression still true?

(B)$$ V_n = V_2 - V_1 = 0$$

**If not, why?**

**NOTE:** This is an open circuit, focusing only on the behavior of the opposing voltages, it the sake of understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example can be considered as a 1-dimensional problem, since the conditions along the horizontal axis are the same everywhere.

However, your second example becomes a 2-dimensional problem, in which you need to consider how current can flow on either side of the lower narrow B field.

So no, your simple expression is no longer true.

Comment: Well, I thought of how the second case would be, I assumed(if it we're a closed circuit) that current will flow expect in the area of \$V_1\$